# meaning of "opinion-molder" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Consider:

> When a rabble-rouser is coming, those organizations should privately expose him to "**opinion-molders**".

I guess, "*opinion-molders*" should be persons who change people's thoughts and outlooks. Based on the meaning of "molder" which is to decay gradually.

Am I correct?

Comment: I've found out that in the original text the words are not placed in quotation marks. Hence, the meaning is not menacing. The opinion-molders are probably of a peaceful kind.

Comment: @CopperKettle May I know how you find that? Probably, the previous edition which is on the google books. I have the hard copy, Sixth Edition. They aren't quite similar. However, the book is 1100 words you need to know.

Comment: Jim Reynolds **[told me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26319732#26319732)**. Basically, the meaning will depend on the context. You can use different methods to mold someone's opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess, "opinion-molders" should be persons who change people's thoughts and outlooks. Based on the meaning of "molder" which is to decay gradually.

You are correct on the first count, but not on the second. The noun **molder** derives from the verb **mold**: "to mold + **er** = **molder**".

> **[Mold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mold)**: 1. to give shape to (the wind molds the waves)
>   2. to form in a mold (to mold candles)
>   3. to determine or influence the quality or nature of (to mold public opinion)

You see, the verb **mold** is different from the verb **molder**.